# Is this use of "protect from" ambiguous?

Tags: phrases

How do you interpret:

> "boys fighting to protect their own insecurities from the world"?

Does it mean the "insecurities" originates from the world? Or it needs to be away from it? Or is this an ambiguity?

(taken from https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/review/revolutionary-girl-utena/episodes-4-5/.115655)

Comment: It's possible to misinterpret almost any sentence if you try hard enough. Standard English usage is you *protect something from something else*.

Comment: Stuart F's comment and Joachim's answer give a reasonable account of the usages of the verb 'protect' and the noun 'insecurities'.  But do they get us to what the writer is is driving at?  I cannot tell, lulalala, without the context.  Could you provide (a) the full sentence and (b) a brief idea of what leads up to it?

Comment: @Tuffy I've added it, thanks! Does it mean you feel it can be interpreted either way?

Comment: They are protecting themselves from the insecurities of the world. They aren't protecting their insecurites.

Comment: @Lambie that's certainly what I thought at first, but can it be interpreted that way literally?

Comment: The insecurity is in the world, not in them. As per your idea.

Answer (score 1):

The ambivalence Stuart F. refers to in the comments aside, I think the most logical interpretation is that **these boys fight (or display aggression) to hide their insecurities from the world**.

Protecting something from the world—apart from literally keeping something safe like a king in his castle—can mean to *isolate* it, to *shelter* it, so the unknown forces of the world cannot touch and corrupt it, and, by extension, find a weakness to undermine.